# "Type of many types" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm totally new to functional programming and Haskell, so I am not sure I asked the question properly or if it makes sense, but I decided to try since I haven't found anything helpful. I'm basically trying to implement a function that can return an `Int`, a `String`, or a List. I know I can use `Either` to return one of two types, but I want to return one of three or more. I tried defining a new type, but I got stuck.

```
data Rets = Int | String | Bool

checkInt :: Rets -> Bool
check x = case x of
    Int x -> True
```

`checkInt` should return `True` if given an `Int`, it is just for testing but I included it anyway.

I'm aware that my question is a mess, so I would be thankful for any kind of explanation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a heads up, don't use backticks for larger pieces of code. Indent it by 4 spaces to format larger bits nicely.

Comment: And what's your question? All you've done is state your end goal, and show some almost complete code.

Comment: You could write `Either Int (Either String Bool)`, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined a type with three constructors that each take 0 arguments. So `Int x` wouldn't be a valid pattern for your type, it would just be `Int -> true`. Of course this also means that you can't store any values in your type, so it doesn't do what you want it to.

What you want is something like this:

```
data Rets = IntRet Int | StringRet String | BoolRet Bool
```

This defines three constructors named `IntRet`, `StringRet` and `BoolRet`, which take an `Int`, `String` and `Bool` respectively. This way you can construct values using `IntRet 42`, `BoolRet True` etc. and then pattern match them as `IntRet x` and so on.

Comment: Yes, that is not exactly what I was looking for, but I'm starting to understand that what I am looking for may not be possible in Haskell. I mean I was trying to do it without those auxiliary constructors, then use some function to know which of those I am trying to return (kind of isType()). Thank you, I will proceed to implement your solution.

Comment: @VladIordache indeed, Haskell's unions are [tagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).